# Get Difference in Arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say I have two arrays such as:

```
$arrayOne = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
$arrayTwo = array(2, 4, 6);
```

How do I get an `$arrayThree`such that:

```
$arrayThree = array(1, 3, 5, 7, 8);
```

Comment: What about [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)?

Comment: @Fabio +1. It's `array_diff()`. I was getting a little confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
 $arrayOne = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
 $arrayTwo = array(2, 4, 6);
 $result = array_diff($arrayOne, $arrayTwo);
 print_r($result);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [2] => 3 [4] => 5 [6] => 7 [7] => 8 )
```

[Documentation.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

Answer (score 0):

Well..you can use the function `array_diff()` to find the difference between the arrays and display the result using `print_r()` function

An example would be

```
<?php
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Will give output like

```
Array
(
[1] => blue
)
```

Comment: This can't be in an comment ?

Comment: an example would be nice, don't you think?

Comment: @ThisUser provided as per the request ..please accept it if it helps..thanx

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php
$arrayOne = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
$arrayTwo = array(2, 4, 6);

$arrayThree = array_diff($arrayOne, $arrayTwo);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arrayThree);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```